# How can I say of a person that he or she has an open or closed personality?

Tags: word-requests, adjectives, english-to-japanese

How can I say of a person that he or she has an open or closed personality? Is there a standard adjective for that?

Comment: Um, when you mention "standard", do you perhaps have a definition somewhere about "open" and "closed" personality? (I'm asking because I'm not good at English nuance.)

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-have-an-open-personality although if you want a dictionary then just apply some of this https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open such as 11 to a person's personality

Comment: @broccoli forest by "standard" holyeyeolo means "used commonly" (between japanese people to describe themselves or others)

Comment: @ericfromabeno & holyeyeolo Oh, thank you, I think I understood (both matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good fit for "open" and "closed personality" are [社交的](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e7%a4%be%e4%ba%a4%e7%9a%84) and [閉鎖的](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e9%96%89%e9%8e%96%e7%9a%84). Informally, you can also use オープン for 社交的.

Comment: I understand that these words almost pin point the right meaning. But are they actually used between Japanese people when speaking of others (to your knowledge)?

Comment: They are actually used, which is why I said they would be "a good fit".

Answer (score 2):

doing a search for: japanese adjectives describing personality

I quickly found this site: http://maggiesensei.com/2015/10/30/%E6%80%A7%E6%A0%BC-seikaku-how-to-describe-personality-in-japanese/

It has a large list of positive and negative personality adjectives, helpfully arranged in categories by similarities.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by open/closed, but the site gives several words that could fit the idea of open:

★ 社交的 (な)  = shakouteki (na) =  outgoing

★ 明るい = akarui = cheerful, bright, happy

★ 元気 (な) = genki (na) = cheerful, energetic

★ 陽気 (な)  = youki (na) = happy, vivacious, upbeat

★ 気さく(な)  = kisaku = friendly

★ さっぱりしている = sappari shite iru = good sport

★ 活発 (な)  = kappatsu (na) = active

★誠実 (な) = seijitsu (na) = sincere

★正直 (な) = shoujiki (na) = honest

★ 愛想がいい = aiso ga ii = friendly, affable

★ 話しやすい  = hanashiyasui = to be easy to talk to

★ 打ち解けやすい  = uchitokeyasui = to be easy to make friends with

★ 付き合いやすい  = tsukiai yasui = to be easy to get along with

And as for "closed", you can take the last 4 in this list and use the opposite of the last word (ie instead of "ii" use "warui" and instead of "yasui" use "nikui") and the meaning would become the opposite.

Comment: You don't really need to put the romaji in there unless the OP specifically asks for it.  Or put it in as furigana (furi-romaji?).

Answer (score 2):

Based on resources OP has provided in their comment, I don't think there is an single all-rounder word to translate the "open" or "close" personality.

The [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-have-an-open-personality),

> To have an open personality is to be open to change. It’s someone who understands that people are imperfect and works with them. [...] Someone who is clear headed enough to see their flaws and admit them. [...] Someone who understands different people have different opinions and that each opinion is a reflection of their experience and observation.

suggests:

- 頭が柔らかい — describes somebody has flexible thinking, though also could be understood as "quick-witted" ↔ (antonym) 頭が固い
- [開明的](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%96%8B%E6%98%8E%E7%9A%84-225912) — willing to accept new things, usually with a connotation to be "progressive" ↔ [頑固](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/47991/meaning/m0u/), [頑迷](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/49802/meaning/m0u/)

The [Merriam-Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open):

> **11 a** : characterized by ready accessibility and usually generous attitude: such as 
>   (1) : generous in giving
>   (2) : willing to hear and consider or to accept and deal with

- [心が広い](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/290917/meaning/m0u/), [おおらか](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/29715/meaning/m0u/) — broad-minded and not being fussy ↔ [心が狭い](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BF%83%E3%81%8C%E7%8B%AD%E3%81%84), [せせこましい](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/124057/meaning/m0u/)
- [寛大](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/48951/meaning/m0u/), [寛容](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/49898/meaning/m0u/) — tolerant, sympathetic and generous ↔ [狭量](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/57206/meaning/m0u/)

> (3) : free from reserve or pretense

- [開放的](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/36997/meaning/m0u/), [開けっぴろげ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/3104/meaning/m0u/) — disclosive and less concealing; note that they are not compliment in some context ↔ [閉鎖的](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/198197/meaning/m0u/)

The loanword オープン is generally associated with the last definition.

Comment: Thank you, this answer broadens the one I've accepted. But again I'd like to ask, are all of these words actually used in conversation?

Comment: @holyeyeolo very much except 開明的, which I think a little old-fashioned.

Comment: I'd like to accept both answers... I think 社交的 and 閉鎖的 definitely sum it up well and answer what I had initially intended to ask. Translating a word does not mean translating it's entire definition, but the feeling it gives the listener and in this case what it would 'allegedly' mean about the subject should it be used to describe it. If I used all the words you gave, eventually the listener would understand 社交的. If that's incorrect, THEN I can accept your answer.

Comment: @holyeyeolo Well... the problem is that I don't really have gut feeling what's "open" personality. 社交的 means "sociable" or "amicable" after all, does it summarize the word?

Comment: If I may replace it with オープン, then I think so. If I knew the answer then I wouldn't ask. The gut feeling is important

Comment: @holyeyeolo Sorry I'm a bit confused. Do you mean you don't have the gut feeling what the English "open personality" mean?

Comment: I don't have the gut feeling for 社交的, since I haven't been able to use it in conversation yet. The answer I've accepted convinced me it should be the closest word in Japanese to replace the gut feeling for the English "open personality," which I do understand

Comment: @holyeyeolo I have the gut feeling for Japanese 社交的, which is a popular word to tell a person is willing to interact with people and good at it, while don't for English "open (and closed) personality".

Comment: And I'm hoping the author of the accepted answer has a gut feeling for both. If not then anyone is welcome to correct him. Sorry, your answer is very good, I think students will prefer your answer. But translators will always go with the accepted answer, assuming it's correct. I hope you can understand